# having problems with if statement with arraylist

Tags: java

So basically i am working on making a program that takes the ID number of some patients in a hospital and shows the record of one particular patient that the user wants to see by typing in that patient's ID number.. I am able to store information of different patients and stuff but when i have to use the if statement to print the record of one particular patient, it doesn't work! and i get an error on the if statement :/ here is the program :-

```
package samplee.java;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class patient$ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<patientss> patient1= new ArrayList<patientss>();
        Scanner src= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner stc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int id,it,num,i;
        String name;
        int ages;
        System.out.println(" j");
        Boolean leave = false;
        while(!leave){
            patientss xx= new patientss();
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's ID ");
            System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
            id=src.nextInt();
            if(id != -1){
            xx.setId(id);

        } 
            System.out.println("Enter the patient's name ");
        System.out.println("-1 to finish entering");
        name=stc.next();
        if(id != -1){
            xx.setName(name);
            patient1.add(xx);
        } 
            else { leave = true; }//Escape the while loop.
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of a student");
        it=sc.nextInt();
        patientss tt= new patientss();
        for(i=0;i<patient1.size();i++){
            {
            tt=patient1.get(i);
        if(it==tt) // this is the statement that isn't working and is showing error.
            System.out.println(tt.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and yea here is the class for patientss

```
package samplee.java;

public class patientss {
int id;
String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String toString(){
    return name+" "+id;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write: "and i get an error on the if statement" - *always* say what the error is when you report that you're getting an error. Is it a compile-time error? An exception at execution time? Also, please reduce your code to a [mcve] - I strongly suspect that most of the code you've presented isn't required for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
it=sc.nextInt();
patientss tt= new patientss();
...
if(it==tt)
```

it and tt are different types, int and patientss respectively. Your code should (probably) be:

```
if(it==tt.getID())
```

Also, your naming convention is weird, you should Capitalise the first letter of you classes' name and dont't use $ and other symbols in them.